# SpriteKit scene deformed after modal presentation swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Could use some help troubleshooting an issue with a SpriteKit scene.
I have a scene that displays some coins in the main section of the app.
When I present a viewcontroller from the bottom I have no issue. Same for tab bar navigation, no issues.
[Here is the view as it should always be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fGLT.png).

The issue comes only when I present a viewcontroller from the side.
 When the new viewcontroller is dismissed, the scene works, but is distorted.
[this is how it is displayed after a viewcontroller is displayed modally and later on dismissed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2GIR.png).
EDIT: I forgot to mention that if I swipe vertically on the distorted scene, the distortion is fixed and all is good.
Here is some of the code in viewDidAppear of the viewcontroller.
Thanks for the help.
EDIT 2:
I just tested the app on a iPhone 5 using iOS 10 and the issue doesn't happen. Any chance this might be iOS 11 related?

```
func configureScene(_ completion: () -> Void) {
    defer { completion() }

    guard wScene == nil else { return }

    let skView = SKView(frame: self.view.frame)
    skView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    skView.backgroundColor = .clear

    wScene = WScene(size: view.frame.size)
    wScene.backgroundColor = .clear
    skView.presentScene(wScene)
    view.insertSubview(skView, belowSubview: collectionView)

    if let buttonsObstacle = doubleButton?.buttonsView {
        let obstacleSize = CGSize.init(width: buttonsObstacle.frame.width, height: buttonsObstacle.frame.height)
        obstacle = SKSpriteNode.init(color: .clear, size: obstacleSize)
        guard let obstacle = obstacle else { return }
        obstacle.name = WScene.obstacleNodeName

        let convertedOrigin = view.convert(buttonsObstacle.center, from: buttonsObstacle.superview)
        let skConvertedOrigin = skView.convert(convertedOrigin, to: wScene)
        obstacle.position = skConvertedOrigin

        obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: obstacleSize)
        obstacle.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        obstacle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        source.scrollHandler = { [weak self] (scrollView) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.buttonsMoved(inView: skView, withScroll: scrollView)
        }
        wScene.addChild(obstacle)

        presenter.loadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put this line :  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just tried putting that line after: self.configureScene {} in the viewDidAppear but it doesn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: And if you put this to the start of viewDidLoad function ?

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately.
Something I forgot to mention is that if I swipe vertically on the distorted scene, the distortion is fixed and all is good.

Comment: And if you set clipToBounds of your UIImageView to true ?

Comment: skView.clipsToBounds = true doesn't change anything. :(

Comment: skView is your coins ?

Comment: Your problem is your SKView size is changing , before it is the size of the entire screen because self.view is the size of the full screen, but after, your view size is that of the inside navigation controller.

Comment: I see... if I'm not asking too much do you have any code I can try to fix the issue? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: There is a scaleMode property on SKScene instance, your wScene so try playing with that.  Also check to make sure any scale mode on the .sks file is set to 1

Comment: I noticed that if I remove this line from the above code --> guard wScene == nil else { return }
the coins don't stretch anymore but I have a different issue: when I swipe down to reload some data the 2 white buttons follow the swipe movement (as they should) but the coins stay there instead of following the white buttons. It is ugly because the coins appear to stand on some invisible obstacles now that the buttons move up or down.

Comment: I just tested the app on a iPhone 5 using iOS 10 and the issue doesn't happen. Any chance this might be iOS 11 related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue.
It was related to the new iOS 11 adjustedContentInset property.
My Coin SK scene was being moved by the scroll handler when the view appeared after a modal transition.
My solution is to disable the scrolling for the first 0.1 second after the view appears. In this way iOS 11 doesn't touch the coins anymore while users are able to scroll correctly because they interact with the view most of the time after at least 0.1 seconds.